# Is there a measure of the failure of the Alexander polynomial to distinguish knots?

Tags: knot-theory, alexander-polynomial

Has there been any research into something like the ratio of distinct Alexander-indistinguishable knots to total knots (up to some measure of complexity)? This was a random question asked of me by a student, and I have no idea (though my gut feeling is that this is far too much to ask).

Comment: I suppose it depends on your sense of complexity.  If you use something geometric that is readily relateable to the Alexander polynomial (say, JSJ decompositions) then there are simple answers: usually there are infinitely many Alexander-indistinguishable knots for "most" knots.  But if your sense of complexity is one that's difficult to relate to geometry (like crossing number) then there's little known.